# How to create an array according to row and column number

Tags: matlab

I want to create an array according to row number and column number.

For example :

```
row_number   Column_number    Value
  1               1            5
  3               2           10
  4               6            4
  7               5           66
```

The array should look like :

```
A=


 5   0   0   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0   0   0
 0  10   0   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0   0   4
 0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0  66   0
```

Otherwise it will print zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 possible methods to this regularly asked question:

**1. Using the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function**

```
A = zeros(max(row_number), max(Column_number));
idx = sub2ind(size(A),row_number, Column_number);
A(idx) = Value;
```

**2. Calculating the [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) manually**

```
A = zeros(max(row_number), max(Column_number));
idx = row_number(:,1) + (Column_number(:,2)-1)*size(A,1)
A(idx) = Value;
```

**3. Use a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix**

```
sparse(row_number, Column_number, Value)
```

And then call [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html?searchHighlight=full) on that if you want to convert it to a regular matrix